# How do I configure the identifier for a custom DTO operation without using annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Created a very simple resource based on a DTO. All the logic is going to be provided via a custom `DataProvider`, and for this project no annotations are used.

The configuration for the resource is:

```xml
<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata">
    <resource class="App\Domain\Dto\ProductUpgradePrice">

        <collectionOperations>
            <collectionOperation name="get"/>
        </collectionOperations>

        <itemOperations>
            <itemOperation name="get"/>
        </itemOperations>

    </resource>
</resources>
```

The actual DTO is:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Domain\Dto;

/** @psalm-immutable */
class ProductUpgradePrice
{

    public function __construct(
        public string $productId,
        public int $regularPrice,
        public int $upgradePrice
    ) {}

}
```

When I try to `GET /api/product_upgrade_prices` I get:

> No identifiers defined for resource of type App\Domain\Dto\ProductUpgradePrice

Which makes sense.

The [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/#identifiers) mention using the annotation `@ApiProperty`, but as I mentioned earlier, no annotations for this project. <sup><sub>(I submitted a PR to [update](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/pull/1250/files) the docs since I posted the question, which was merged, so hopefully future users will not get in the same situation)</sub></sup>

I've tried adding this to the resource configuration:

```xml
<property name="productId">
    <attribute name="identifier">true</attribute>
</property>
```

But got the same results.

How could I configure this without using annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [metadata XSD](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/6682c1880686833dcf59a2dc06e9c6f03888e89d/src/Metadata/schema/metadata.xsd), in line [113](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/6682c1880686833dcf59a2dc06e9c6f03888e89d/src/Metadata/schema/metadata.xsd#L113) you can see this attribute for the `property` element:

```xml
<xsd:attribute type="xsd:boolean" name="identifier"/>
```

Which mean you should use this instead:

```xml
<property identifier="true" name="id" />
```